# How to feed input in an c++ executable using NodeJS's child_process?

Tags: c++, node.js, child-process

I have installed mingw in my system to be able to compile c++ programs using terminal. I am creating a NodeJs api which when called with the C++ code and input compiled and generates output. For this I am using child_process of NodeJS.

Now on terminal, when I open "./a.exe", I need to feed input to it.But how to achieve that in Nodejs.
Right now I am just able to compile the program that does not require inputs.

```
const compile_run = async (input) => {
  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec("g++ hello.cpp", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
      }
      if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
      }
      exec("./a", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
          return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
          console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
          return;
        }
        resolve(stdout)
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Before you go and write `make` or `CMake`, why not just use those tools?

Comment: I didn' get it.I have a react website and then I am just passing my code writing it to hello.cpp and executing the commands.

Comment: I think you should focus on one problem at a time. Do you get any errors here?

Comment: If you're looking to feed data to this, you'll need to use [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) where you can stream to `stdin` and read from `stdout`.

Comment: No I am not getting errors but I want to feed the input to .exe file right. When you code in c++ there's some input. So my concern is using the terminal I am able to write the input when I open the ./a.exe file but how to do the exact same thing usng nodejs

Comment: I did tried it once .Ohk so I will check spawn() once again and then let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to set stdin of spawn to a input string that I am fetching from an API.Can you help?

Comment: `spawn()` returns a handle that you can then attach to, like `let exe = spawn(...)` then `exe.stdin.pipe()` to wherever you want.

Comment: See this. I want to provide "4 5" as an input to spawn and this is giving me error.  `const child = spawn("a");
  const input = "4 5";
  child.stdin.pipe(input);
  child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`child stdout:\n${data}`);
  });` .

Comment: Read up on how streams work. It's a little tricky, but they're very flexible.

Comment: Well I figured it out. `const input = "4 5"; child.stdin.write(input);
child.stdin.end();` and it works.

Comment: Worth writing up as a self-answer with the complete code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your instant replies and finally bringing me to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is my hello.cpp file:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<"Sum "<<a+b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the way I will compile this program with the necessary inputs using child processes in nodejs.

```
const { exec, spawn } = require("child_process");
exec("g++ hello.cpp", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }

  const child = spawn("./a"); //where a is the exe file generated on compiling the code.
  child.stdin.write("4 5");
  child.stdin.end();
  child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`child stdout:\n${data}`);
  });
});
```

The way you should provide the inputs to stdin of spawn is using the write() method and the end() method.

Comment: A great approach, just some small fixes: ```const child = spawn("./a")``` should be ```const child = spawn("./a.out")``` and hello.cpp should be renamed sum.cpp if you don't mind me being nitpicking